# Pause all instances of mb.YTPlayer element on single button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

Using a jquery plugin for Youtube backgrounds (https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer/wiki)

I am trying to pause all the background videos with a single pause button, not sure for which reason it only pauses the first video, no matter the length of divs with background video.

I set up a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2eLcbm3L/) explaining what I am trying to achieve.

The codes are as follow:

```
$('.vid').each(function() {
    var vid = $(this).data('video');
    $(this).YTPlayer({
        videoURL: vid,
        stopMovieOnBlur: false,
        mute: true,
        ratio: 'auto',
        quality: 'default',
        loop: true,
        showYTLogo: false,
        showControls: false,
        containment: 'self'
    });

});

$('.pauseit').on('click', function() {
    $('.vid').YTPPause()
});
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Why not use the each that you used in the first statement? `$('.vid').each(function() { $(this).YTPPause() });`

Comment: It returns the following error: 'Cannot read property 'pauseVideo' of undefined' when doing so.

Comment: It does return the correct amount when logging it though: console.log($('.vid').length) => returns 2 (for the set up demo), added in the click event.

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/swnj2bcg/

Comment: Indeed it does, weird. Thanks so much, post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comment to answer.

1. Make sure the button is a button: `type="button"`
2. use .each again to pause the videos:

Like this:

```
$('.pauseit').on('click', function() {
    $('.vid').each(function() { $(this).YTPPause(); });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/swnj2bcg/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here. I modified the jsfiddle:

[update](https://jsfiddle.net/2eLcbm3L/1/)

Chnage it like this:

```
 $('.pauseit').on('click', function() {
    $('.vid').each(function() {
      $( this ).YTPPause();
    })
 });
```

Comment: I did not see your comment I just modify it in the fiddle and add a link, and normally if your comment is the solution just set it as an answer so everyone could see that it is already answered.